# Convert GeoPackage to ESRI shapefile format

Tags: qgis, shapefile, ogr2ogr, esri-geodatabase, geopackage

I learned that to convert a DWG file with all its layers from AutoCAD to an ESRI shapefile format in QGIS, one has to first import it as a GeoPackage, and then convert it from a GeoPackage to a shapefile. I already did that. But there's no option to convert the GeoPackages to ESRI shapefiles in QGIS. One can only export the gpkg layers to a QGIS layer definition. I have tried installing and using the Qpackage plugin with QGIS already, but it didn't work. I also tried ogr2ogr for the conversion it didn't still work.

I need to convert the layers from my GeoPackage to the same layers in ESRI shapefile formats.

EDITS: I have attached an Image of the viewport showing the GPKG layers I imported from QGIS. Whenever I right-click on the gpkg layer [ME_AREA 1], and navigate to export, it doesn't bring up the option to save to a shapefile. Instead it brings "save as a layer definition" I really don't know what else to try at this stage.

[image: image showing the gpkg layers]

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to export a gpkg to ESRI-Shapefile? As long as there is no real need to do so, I see no point in this conversion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your data looks exactely, but the normal workflow to convert from Geopackage to Shapefile is:

version a) Menu Layer - Safe as - select ESRI Shapefile as format
version b) Richt-click the Geopackage-layer - export - safe feature as - select ESRI Shapefile as format.

[image]

If this doesn't work, provide more details about your data, maybe including a screenshot.

Comment: Thank you, I have already added a screenshot and more information to the question. It doesn't bring up this option for me like you have in your screenshot above.

Comment: Are your data georeferenced at all? Do they show up in the right place if you put a basemap in the background?

Comment: No I have not cheked it. Could that be the reason why I can't convert them to a shapefile?

Comment: If you have a georeferenced layer try with this if you can export it with theoptions I have. If you dont have any, download from https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/

Comment: I want to convert these GPKG groups in the image above to individual ESRI shapefile formats. Do you think that If I do or do not georeference the GPGK layers first the task would be impossible?

Comment: If you could share your data or at least a part of it I could test it with my QGIS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108151/discussion-between-victor-e-irekponor-and-babel).